# Allow line editing when reading input from the command line

Tags: swift, macos, user-input, filehandle

I already know how to get the input from user keyboard. 
I can use the `readLine()` method or

```
 let input = FileHandle.standardInput
 let inputData = input.availableData
 var text = String(data: inputData, encoding: .utf8)
```

But the two methods get also when the user press an arrow key button.
I would like to filter the input in order to remove these data. I want that the user can write something, maybe go back with the left arrow key, change something and insert the data without problem.
Thanks!

Comment: I assume that you are asking about a macOS command line tool, not about an iOS application?

Comment: Yes , macOs command Line tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the “line editing feature” which is provided by [libedit](http://thrysoee.dk/editline/) on macOS.

In order to use it from a Swift command line tool, you need to

- `#include <readline/readline.h>` in the bridging header file,
- add “libedit.tbd” to the “Link Binary With Libraries” section in the
  “Build Phases” of your target.

Here is a minimal example Swift program:

```
while let cString = readline("prompt>") {
    let line = String(cString: cString)
    free(cString)
    print(line)
}
```

*Important:* You have to run this in the Terminal, it won't work properly in the Xcode debugger console.

Each input line can be edited before entering <kbd>Return</kbd>,
similar to what you can do in the Terminal. And with

```
while let cString = readline("prompt>") {
    add_history(cString) // <-- ADDED
    let line = String(cString: cString)
    free(cString)
    print(line)
}
```

you can even use the up/down arrow keys to navigate to previously entered
lines.

For more information, call `man 3 readline` in the Terminal.

Here is a possible helper function:

```
func readlineHelper(prompt: String? = nil, addToHistory: Bool = false) -> String? {
    guard let cString = readline(prompt) else { return nil }
    defer { free(cString) }
    if addToHistory { add_history(cString) }
    return(String(cString: cString))
}
```

Usage example:

```
while let line = readlineHelper(addToHistory: true) {
    print(line)
}
```